# boost::bind for void pointer argument

Tags: boost, void-pointers

How can boost::bind be used for a void pointer argument of a function?

```
boost::bind(foo, _1, boost::ref((void*)this))
```

is (obviously) not correct.

Comment: What's the full signature of `foo`? Is it a member function or a free function?

Comment: It is something like: void foo(const &argument1, Object *obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind is strong typed. Callbacks with `void*` are typically seen in C APIs, there is no need to use it otherwise:

```
struct Object { /* .... */ };

int some_callback(Object& o) // or e.g. a thread function
{
     // use o
}
```

You'd bind or call it as:

```
Object instance;
boost::function<int(Object&)> f = boost::bind(&some_callback, boost::ref(instance));
```

Of course, you can pass by value

```
int by_value(Object o) {}

f = boost::bin(&by_value, instance); // or `std::move(instance)` if appropriate
```

And if you **insist** by pointer (*why?*):

```
int by_pointer(Object* o) {}
f = boost::bin(&by_pointer, &instance);
```

If you want to be really really dirty (or you want to be signature compatible with that C API):

```
int by_void_ptr(void* opaque_pointer) {}
f = boost::bind(&by_void_ptr, &instance);
```